# How to sort data stream by 2 column names (column number may vary)?

Tags: text-processing, awk, pipe, sort

I get a stream of data from an API with which look like this:

```
redID  blueID  whiteID  
1      22       2  
44     15       41  
2      15       15  
31     2       14
```

What I need to do, is to sort this by `blueID` and then `whiteID` and then send somewhere else. But I don't know in advance how many columns there will be. All I know for sure is that there will always be at least those 2 columns.
So the desired output would look like this:

```
redID  blueID  whiteID  
31     2       14  
2      15      15  
44     15      41  
1      22      2
```

Is there a way, perhaps in `awk`, to sort this stream based on a column name?
The only answer that I'm looking for is in a form of:

```
inputStream | some operations | sortedInputStream
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us your desired output. Ideally, show us an example that actually _can_ be sorted. All your lines are identical so this isn't very informative.

Comment: i updated my question. Thanks for pointing this out

Comment: Do you know in advance that `blueID` and `whiteID` will always be the second and third columns, respectively?

Comment: Unfortunately no, the number of columns and their position may change, the only thing that is certain is each column's name.

Comment: Do you care if the output is in the same column order as the input?  (It seems like it would be easier to rearrange the columns and then sort by first and second columns...but maybe not.)

Comment: No, the output columns may be in any order.

Comment: Glad you figured out a solution. Please post it as an answer though instead of editing into your question. You can then [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left, which will mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the ideas from comments and other sources I was finally able to write this code and answer my own question:

```
   inputStream | awk -F'\t' -v OFS="\t" '{
            if ( col1 == ""){
                for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){
                    if ($i == "BlueId"){
                        col1=i;
                    }
                    else if ($i == "WhiteId"){
                        col2=i;
                    }
                }
            print "-1" "\t" "-1" "\t" $0
            }
            else {
                print $col1 "\t" $col2 "\t" $0
            }
        }' | sort -k1,1n -k2,2n | cut -f3- | outputStream
```

It works like this: it takes stream data, finds desired columns' numbers and prints in front of every row both values needed to sort. Then it sorts 1th and 2nd column and deletes them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
 # get the header line from the file and split each header to a different line
 header=$(head -1 $file_name | tr ' ' '\n')
 # get the index/line number of the blueID
 blueID_index=$(echo "$header" | grep -n "blueID" | sed 's/:.*//')
 # same for whiteID
 whiteID_index=$(echo "$header" | grep -n "whiteID" | sed 's/:.*//')
 # now build the sort command with the indexes you just computed
 sort -k$blueID_index -k$whileID_index
```